# java run class using jawin

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to run a class that I wrote that is importing the jawin library.
My command line is as below:
`java -cp C:\class_path ClassName`
I'm getting:
`Exception in thread 'main' java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError org/jawin/funcptr`

What am I doing wrong?

Doesn't the JAR that I'm adding to the build path get into the binary file that I've compiled?
If not, then when I publish my class file how will it know to find the external JAR? What if it doesn't exist on the target computer?

Comment: Add a \\* to the class_path directory or specify the jar names manually. java -cp .;C:\class_path\\* ClassName

Comment: @uraimo  What if the jar doesn't exist on the target computer? Can't I embed it inside the class?

Comment: Both your classes and the library jars are needed on the target, you could merge the jars but i don't see why, you can just distribute them individually.